# Stretch grid when it reach windows bottom

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have page like this design on my small laptop screen

```
.k-grid-content {
    min-height: 200px;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;        
}

_____________________________
|Content                    |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
| Grid                      |
|                           |
+---------+-----------------+
|Bottom Windows screen      |
|                           |
|Grid Bottom                |
|___________________________|
```

Usually the grid's min-height was set up a specific size & the grid bottom was lay down below the windows screen bottom, if i want to see the grid bottom, i have to scroll down or stretch the grid by mouse, and this happen:

```
_____________________________
|Content                    |
|                           |
-----------------------------
| Grid                      |
|                           |
|                           |
|Grid Bottom                |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|                           |
|Bottom Windows screen      |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Obviously the grid always keep its original set up size no matter how much i skretch. is there any way that i can keep the grid bottom at the windows bottom when i skretch it to it min-height like this?

```
_____________________________
|Content                    |
|                           |
-----------------------------
| Grid                      |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           | 
|                           |
|                           |
|Bottom Windows/Grid bottom |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Here's the full code, using kendo tabstrip:

```
function AddReportTab(gridId, textTitle) {
    try {
        if (gridId) {
            var tabRemoved = document.getElementById("tab_" + gridId);
            if (tabRemoved) {
                RemoveTab(tabRemoved, gridId, true);
            }
        }

        tapstripBottom = $("#bottom-tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
        reportArray.push(gridId);
        var newTab = {
            encoded: false,
            text: "<div id='" + "ReportTitle" + gridId + "' onclick='setBottomPanelHeaderCaption(this);'>" + textTitle + "</div>" + ' <i class="fa fa-close" id="tab_' + gridId + '" onclick="RemoveTab(this,\'' + gridId + '\', false);"></i>',
            content: "<div class=\"panel panel-default\" style=\"margin-top: 35px;\"><div id='ReportTab" + gridId + "'>" +   
            "<div class=\"panel-body grid-parent\"><div class=\"grid-bottom\" id='" + gridId + "'></div></div>" +
            "<div style='display:none' id='PopupGetLink" + gridId + "'></div>" +
            "</div>",
        }

        if (tapstripBottom.tabGroup.children().length == 0) {
            tapstripBottom.append(newTab);
        }
        else {
            tapstripBottom.insertBefore(newTab, tapstripBottom.tabGroup.children().eq(0));
        }

        verticalSplitter.expand(".k-pane:last");
        verticalSplitter.trigger("resize");

        tapstripBottom.select("li:first");
        setBottomPanelHeaderCaption($("#ReportTitle" + gridId)[0]);

        $("#" + "ReportTitle" + gridId + "").css({ "display": "inline-block" });
        if ($("#" + "ReportTitle" + gridId + "").width() > $(document).width() / 6) {
            $("#" + "ReportTitle" + gridId + "").css({
                "width": $(document).width() / 6, "white-space": "nowrap", "overflow": "hidden", "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
            });
        }


    } catch (exception) {
        window.location = userErrorPageUrl;
    }
}
```

Here's the original grid when i first open it 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q478e.jpg)

Here the grid after i streth using mouse 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbi1c.jpg)

The arrow point at grid bottom, as you can see, it doesn't change size when i stretch it. I want to make it to auto fit with the bottom screen

Comment: Your diagrams are hard to understand. Is there a way you could include pictures of what's happening and what you're looking for instead?

Comment: @Keara please have a look at my update

Comment: That's better. I don't think I know how to answer your question, but it is definitely clearer what you're asking now, so hopefully someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: Have you looked at this article: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/resize-grid-when-the-window-is-resized